# How can i reach frame title inside Handler

Tags: java

I can't reach my title inside Handler.

Example of my code:

```
public Frame extends JFrame {

public Frame() {
    super("Frame 1");
        .
        .
        .
```

There needs to be a button in my GUI and whenever you click it, it needs to change the title from Frame 1 to Frame 2, and vice versa.

```
ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();
        .
        .
        .
}
 class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            JButton but = (JButton) event.getSource();
            if (??.getTitle(equals("Frame 1"))) {
                setTitle("Frame 2");
            } else {
                setTitle("Frame 1");
            }
```

So everytime I click the button all it does is the else part. I can't use the getTitle inside my if :/

Answer (score 2):

First it should read

```
if (??.getTitle().equals("Frame 1"))
```

Otherwise you call `equals` on the `ButtonHandler` instance and just test, if that instance is equal to the String `"Frame 1"`...

Then I'd add a constructor to `ButtonHandler` that takes a frame instance and stores it internally. My suggestion in total:

```
class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
  private JFrame frame;
  public ButtonHandler(JFrame frame) {
     this.frame = frame;
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    JButton but = (JButton) event.getSource();
    if (frame.getTitle().equals("Frame 1")) {
        setTitle("Frame 2");
    } else {
        setTitle("Frame 1");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When i write if(frame.getTitle(equals"Frame 1"))) it says; 

The method getTitle() in the type Frame is not applicable for the arguments (boolean)

I don't know where i have boolean.

Comment: @osmancan: equals(..) returns a boolean and you don't to pass that as a parameter.  Rather the getTitle() method should have no parameters.

Comment: What I want to do is, in my if condition I want it to get the title and check if it equals to "Frame 1" and change it to "Frame 2" vice versa. But I can't seem to manage it :|

Comment: I tried getTitle() == "Frame 1"
well actually i set String f1 = "Frame 1" and
getTitle() == (f1)
and it fixed my problem.

Comment: @Osmancan - do **not** use `==` with Strings (here). Look at my example and use `equals` exactly like I did. For the moment - just do it. You'll understand later.

Comment: @Osmancan, @Andreas: There was a typo in the answer, it should have been `frame.getTitle().equals(...)` instead of `frame.getTitle(equals(...))`. (I changed this.)

Comment: Stupid me - copy pasted the original and didn't pay attention to correct it. Sorry & thanks to Paulo!